# String Hibernate transactions

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

I have inherited an application which uses Spring with Hibernate.  I am trying to create a new API method to perform a unit of work.  This unit of work should be done in a single DB transaction so that if anything goes wrong all changes are rolled back.

The application appears to have been set up to use transactions so I have added the transaction annotation to my new method. Here is a simplified version my new method.

```
@Transactional(readOnly=false, propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackFor={IllegalMemberException.class, InvalidPasswordException.class, IllegalDomainException.class})
private ApiResponse mergeUsersWork(Member fromMember, Member toMember) 
throws IllegalMemberException, InvalidPasswordException, IllegalDomainException 
{
    //Update the members details
    Date now = new Date();
    MemberPropertiesParameters mpp = new MemberPropertiesParameters();
    mpp.set(MemberField.LLI, now);
    mpp.set(MemberField.LLO, now);
    fromMember = memberManager.updateMember(fromMember, mpp);

    //Enter the from user GUID - we should be able to use this to back out any cock-ups 
    toMember.setObject(MemberField.MERGED_FROM_MEMBER_ID, fromMember.getObject(MemberField.MERGED_FROM_MEMBER_ID));
    memberManager.updateMember(toMember, null);

    if(1==1) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Blah Blah Blah");
    }

    ApiResponse apiResponse = new ApiResponse("members");
    apiResponse.getResponseHeader().setDetail("Users merged successfully.");
    apiResponse.setResponseData(new ApiResponseData(MemberTO.createTO(toMember, toMember.getOrganisation())));
    return apiResponse;
}
```

Running through this with a debugger I found that the member update on line 10

```
fromMember = memberManager.updateMember(fromMember, mpp);
```

gets written to the DB as soon as the line returns, and not at the end of the method.  So any exceptions thrown after that have no effect as the commit appears to have occurred.  I have checked for and removed all flushes.  The updateMember method signature propagates the transaction as it should

```
@Transactional(readOnly=false, propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
public Member updateMember(Member member, MemberPropertiesParameters args) 
throws IllegalMemberException, InvalidPasswordException
```

I am now at the limit of my knowledge, and short of spending a few weeks learning all this stuff I was hoping someone might be able to point me in the right direction.

Many thanks

Comment: I have updated my method to handle exceptions correctly (see above).  For debugging purposes I have explicitly added a line to throw a RuntimeException.  Still the data is permanently written to the DB - i.e. no rollback?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that something was written to the DB doesn't mean that your transaction was committed.
Flush just instructs hibernate to issue all queries performed in the current session, but transaction can still be rolled back.

You can debug you code and check if call to your class is wrapped in transactional proxy.

One more thing.
Your method is declared to throw Exception.
Any RuntimeException will trigger rollback, and any checked Exception will not.
So if IllegalMemberException, InvalidPasswordException are check exceptions you have to add:

@Transactional(rollbackFor={IllegalMemberException.class, InvalidPasswordException.class})

Edit:

I haven't seen it before. Your method is **private**. It has to be **public** otherwise spring will not be able to apply aspect that handles transactions.

I don't know how you call your method but transactions are handled by a proxy. It means that even if your method is public and annotated with @Transactional but you call it from a method inside your class that is not transactional, there will be no transaction! Read about spring AOP.

Comment: When I say something is written to the DB I mean I can see the updated data in the Toad UI. Surely I should not be able to see the data in an on going transaction from another transaction!!!

Comment: Thanks for the help - I have finally got it to work.  I have split the method out into another class.  The instantiation of this class is done within the Spring context via @Autowire.  It also appears that transaction management was not configured properly - I had to add <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringSessionContext</prop> to the session factory configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really getting such affect? It cannot be.

You should know, that `@Transactional` annotation will **wrap** target method inside `Spring Aspect`. It will be called **before** and **after** method execution.

**On before** it will consider if any on going transaction is and what is propagation level. If joined transaction exists and propagation is required - it will be executed inside same transaction. On the other hand, it will creates new specific for target method.

**On after** - it will commit/rollback transaction.

IF **ANY** transactional related exception will occur - it will be **runtime exception** and you should NOT CATCH IT!

So, if you really getting such situation, you should debug aspect which is around your method. ALSO your member manager should update/commit/merge in same transaction - if it is not the same, so that's why it updates your model before target method execution ends.